# Background cover image offset in x direction without any white space

Tags: html, css, background-image, cover

Probably a basic question, but i'm trying to offset a background cover image to the right at a certain media query. However I added that to the css and when it reaches the media queries it works, but if i scale a certain way there is white space. I would like to maintain the cover image properties where no matter how you rescale there is no white space. Currently I have a cropped image to load on the media query so this doesn't happen, but i'd rather just have one image that loads because there is not much difference in file size.

Comment: can you show an example? isolate the code?

Comment: Do you mean that you are using the CSS property "background:cover"?

Comment: So let's say i have an image with dimensions 800h x 1000w. Once it hit's a media query of 600w, i want the image to be cropped from the right at 800h x 700w (not scaled/squished). How do I do this? I have two different image files being used right now, i'd like to just use one.